# Пересоздаётся ли словарь при каждом вызове функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, dict

Есть фунция:

```
def foo(...):
    my_dict = { 
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Я всегда думал, что при каждом вызове такой функции словарь `my_dict` будет каждый раз создаваться заново. Но при проверке оказалось, что `id(my_dict)` одинаковый от вызова к вызову. При этом, если даже менять словарь внутри функции, то словарь остаётся прежним при новом вызове фунции, но `id` у него всё равно не меняется.

Соответсвенно, вопросы:

Создаётся ли словарь при каждом вызове функции?

Как так получается, что у объекта один и тот же `id`, но он не накапливает изменения при новых вызвах функции?

```
def foo(x):
    a = {1: 2, 4:5}
    a[x] = x**2
    print(id(a), a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(5):
        foo(i)


2581778427192 {1: 2, 4: 5, 0: 0}
2581778427192 {1: 1, 4: 5}
2581778427192 {1: 2, 4: 5, 2: 4}
2581778427192 {1: 2, 4: 5, 3: 9}
2581778427192 {1: 2, 4: 16}
```

Comment: Интересно, что пересоздание словаря происходит по той же ссылке до тих пор пока словаре не возвращается из функции. Проверьте: `return a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В соответствии с документацией https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id объекты, у которых срок жизни не пересекается, могут имень одинаковый id. 
Получается, что по выходу из функции словарь удаляется, его id становится вакантым и выдается под тот-же словарь, но уже при следующем вызове функции. Следующий код подтвержает эту теорию. Тот-же id будет выдан под словарь уже и в другую функцию.

```
def boo(x):
    b = {'p': 1, 'q': 0}
    print(id(b))

def foo(x):
    a = {1: 2, 4:5}
    print(id(a), a)
    return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo(0)
    foo(1)
    boo(0)
    foo(2)
>>>
1899014090040 {1: 2, 4: 5}
1899014090040 {1: 2, 4: 5}
1899014090040
1899014090040 {1: 2, 4: 5}
```

В свою очередь, если пересечь время жизни этих словарей, то всё становится на свои места, id словарям выдаются новые:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a1 = foo(0)
    a2 = foo(1)
    boo(0)
    a3 = foo(2)
    a4 = foo(3)
>>>
2388301606200 {1: 2, 4: 5}
2388301606632 {1: 2, 4: 5}
2388301606272 
2388301606272 {1: 2, 4: 5}
2388332816064 {1: 2, 4: 5}
```

Ну и маленькая проверка, что словарики, таки, создаются новые:

```
COUNTER = 0
class Fake:
    def __init__(self):
        global COUNTER
        COUNTER += 1
        print("A new version of me has been created. Counter = ", COUNTER)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(COUNTER)

def foo(x):
    a = {1: 2, 4:Fake()}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo(0)
    foo(1)
    foo(2)
>>>
A new version of me has been created. Counter =  1
A new version of me has been created. Counter =  2
A new version of me has been created. Counter =  3
```

Comment: А в Вашем примере  создание словаря не связано с тем, что Fake() в потенциале может быть динамическим объектом?  Что на самом деле происходит с константами?